# Lithium: Show confirm box when link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, lithium

I have a lithium Html helper link

```
<?php echo $this->html->link('Delete', array('action' => 'delete', 'args' => $id); ?>
```

When this link is clicked I would like a confirm box to show up, but I can't see anything in the documentation that would allow me to do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: not sure it will work, but try adding a third argument: `$options = array('onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by Dvir Volk this can be solved using the following:

```
<?php echo $this->html->link('Delete', array('action' => 'delete', 'args' => $id), array('onclick', 'return confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this item?")'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to add an event to it.

```
<?php echo $this->html->link (
    'Delete', 
    array(
        'action' => 'delete', 
        'args' => $id, 
        'class' => 'delete'
    )
); ?>

<script>
    $('a.delete').click(function(){
        confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this item?");
    });
</script>
```